# Retrieve all objects related to a particular foreign key in django

Tags: python, django

I have the following models.py:

```
//models.py(code snippet)
class userresp(models.Model):

    uid=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True,null=True)
    resp=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    datetime=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{} {}".format(self.uid,self.datetime)

    class Meta:
        db_table="userresp"
```

I want to retrieve all "resp" pertaining to the value of a particular uid=3.
there are two records in the table userresp with uid=3. How to do that?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `uid` is a not a good name for the field. Sth. like `user` is a better fit, since given a `userresp` (class names should be camel case, btw) instance `resp`, `resp.uid` will give you a `User` **instance**, not its id. You can get the id via `resp.uid_id` (this makes the misnaming obvious). 
Anyway,

```
resps = userresp.objects.filter(uid_id=3)
```

will work. If you have the `User` instance, use the [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) of the fk field, e.g.:

```
user = get_user_model().objects.get(id=3)
resps = user.userresp_set.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

`resps = userresp.objects.filter(uid_id=3)` should work.
But you have some issues with your code. First, class names should be <s>capitalized</s> CamelCase.

Try this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserResp(models.Model):

    user=models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    resp=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    datetime=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{} {}".format(self.user.id, self.datetime)
```

Then you could use:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=3)
resps = UserResp.objects.filter(user=user)
```